# assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast c[a0][4]="YES"; i cant get it what is wrong int it integer t is already decleared

Tags: c, string

warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
             c[a0][4]="YES"; i cant get it what is wrong int it integer t is already decleared

```
char c[t][4];
for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++)
{
    int n; 
    int k; 
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);
    int a[n];
    for(int a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++)
    {
       scanf("%d",&a[a_i]);
       if(a[a_i]<=0)
       {
           count++;
       }

    }
    if(count>=k)
     c[a0][4]="NO";
    else
        c[a0][4]="YES";
    count=0;

}
for(int p=0;p<t;p++)
    printf("%c \n",c[p][4]);
```

Comment: You can't use `=` to copy strings in C. Use `strcpy`.

Comment: And even then `c[a0][4]="NO";` breaks the bounds of the array, which may be indexed only up to `c[t-1][3]`.

Answer (score 0):

c is an array of array of char. You can't set a char equal to a string.